# SELECT rows with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, select, duplication

I have a table of names in `mysql` InnoDB as

```
Firstname        Lastname
Steve            Ross
John             Doe
J.               Doe
Mike             Ross
Michael          Ross
Roger            Jackson
```

I want to SELECT rows in which there are duplicates against `first letter of Firstname + Lastname`.

For the example table, SELECT query should return

```
John             Doe
J.               Doe
Mike             Ross
Michael          Ross
```

Comment: Did you try anything to get this result?

Comment: @bluefeet I tried `INNER JOIN` but no success yet.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'd include in your question you attempts. Right now, this is written as a do my work for me type of question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's mysql. My bad, I included in the question.

Comment: @bluefeet no it is not that way. When I do not have any clue what is the right track, my random attempts are just misleading in the question. Even if someone answer what method can work for this purpose, it is a perfect answer for me, I will struggle with coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT B.firstname,B.lastname FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1)) nametag,COUNT(1) rcount
    FROM names GROUP BY CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1))
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1)) nametag,
    firstname,lastname FROM names
) B USING (nametag);
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS alldb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE alldb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE alldb
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE names
    -> (
    ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->   firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO names (firstname,lastname) VALUES
    -> ('Steve','Ross'),('John','Doe'),('J.','Doe'),
    -> ('Mike','Ross'),('Michael','Ross'),('Roger','Jackson');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM names;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | lastname | firstname |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Ross     | Steve     |
|  2 | Doe      | John      |
|  3 | Doe      | J.        |
|  4 | Ross     | Mike      |
|  5 | Ross     | Michael   |
|  6 | Jackson  | Roger     |
+----+----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT B.firstname,B.lastname FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1)) nametag,COUNT(1) rcount
    ->     FROM names GROUP BY CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1))
    ->     HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    -> ) A
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT CONCAT(lastname,LEFT(firstname,1)) nametag,
    ->     firstname,lastname FROM names
    -> ) B USING (nametag);
+-----------+----------+
| firstname | lastname |
+-----------+----------+
| John      | Doe      |
| J.        | Doe      |
| Mike      | Ross     |
| Michael   | Ross     |
+-----------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: works like a charm. absolutely marvelous!